# console window on top with Python?

Tags: python, windows

How do I force my console window to be always on top with Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ensure that the application windows is always on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678966/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-application-windows-is-always-on-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a console window written by yourself as a "real" window you can alter the state of, you'd have to talk to the window manager (be it Windows's or some of the Linux ones).

But I agree with Paul Tomblin. I think most window managers have that feature built in for users to activate it if they WANT it on top!

Answer (score 3):

Don't.  There's nothing worse than two windows that think they deserve to be the one on top fighting it out.  I've seen CPUs dragged to their knees by it.