# How can I ensure that the application windows is always on top?

Tags: python, windows

I have a simple Python script that runs in a console windows.

How can I ensure that the console window is always on top and if possible resize it?

Comment: A bit confused - Are you running this from a different window/box and you want are opening up a new cmd window or are you talking about executing the python script in the cmd window wanting it to stay on top for the duration of execution?

Comment: exactly... executing the script (double click on it) and staying on top

Comment: What is the high-level goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: the console window of my script staying always on top until I close it.. thats my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with the cmd window, you'll probably have to invoke a lot of win32 calls.

1. Enumerate all the windows using win32gui.EnumWindows to get the window handles
2. Find the "window title" that matches how you run your program.  For example, doubling clicking on a .py file on my system the window title is "C:\Python26\python.exe".  Running it on a command line, it is called c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - c:\python26\python.exe test.py
3. Using the appropriate title get the cmd window handle.
4. Using [win32gui.SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) make your window a "top-most" window, etc...

---

```
import win32gui, win32process, win32con
import os

windowList = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(lambda hwnd, windowList: windowList.append((win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd),hwnd)), windowList)
cmdWindow = [i for i in windowList if "c:\python26\python.exe" in i[0].lower()]
win32gui.SetWindowPos(cmdWindow[0][1],win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,100,100,0) #100,100 is the size of the window
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678966/how-can-i-let-the-application-screen-always-on-top-python/3679395#3679395) I arrived at this:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,100,100,200,200,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating your own window, you can use Tkinter to create an "always on top" window like so:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.mainloop()
```

And then put whatever you want to have happen within the main loop.

If you are talking about the command prompt window, then you will have to use some Windows-specific utilities to keep that window on top. You can [try this script for Autohotkey](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/).